# memory initialization and viewdidload and order of event execution

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, viewdidload

I am trying to load a list of assets using the ALAssetsLibrary and enumerateGroupsWithTypes. I populate an NSMutableArrary with the assets loaded so i get to use it later, for instance change a view's background randomly.

I tried to preload this array with the assets in the ViewDidLoad method and only to find out that it gets handled AFTER the view is loaded.  if I put a NSLog statement after the load method is called, the log will be printed, but no array initialized until the view is completely loaded.

Question is when should I initialize my array then?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidLoad` method does exactly as it suggests - its called once the view is loaded. No surprises there. You could consider loading in the `initWithFrame:` and/or `initWithCoder:` methods, depending on which is relevant to you.

Your question doesn't say much about why you want to load something in this method. What's wrong with loading it in, say, the `viewDidLoad` method and using the array to configure the view before the view will appear? I have no idea how heavy your loading is. But guess what - there's even a handy `viewWillAppear:` method...!